# How can I write the text of QHeaderView's section into a file?

Tags: qt, qabstractitemmodel, qheaderview

I'm trying to write an exporter, which takes in a `QTableView` and writes all its data into a .csv-file, so it can be viewed in MS Excel.

Now I can't seem to find a way to read the text from the horizontal header's sections. There doesn't seem to be a method like `QHeaderView::sections` or something like that, so I can't access the QHeaderView's sections. There is a `QHeaderView::count` though, which makes me think that they are indeed saved in a container somewhere.

So is there a way to get the text of a section of `QHeaderView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`::headerData`](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qabstractitemmodel.html#headerData) method of your model.
To get number of columns you may use `view->model()->columnCount();` method.

Comment: I fear it will come down to that. I was just hoping, there'd be a more convenient solution.

Comment: You should understand Qt MVC pattern. You could not pick data from view. View doesn't know anything about data.

Comment: Yes, of course, that makes sense. But why can I count the sections then? Isn't that a breach of the pattern?

Comment: No it doesn't. You should call `model->columnCount( QModelIndex() );` for that. In ideal case you should design your code to keep all data independend from view.

Comment: I probably _shouldn't_ get the count from the view, but i _could_ if I wanted to, which I find very strange. Anyway, I followed your suggestion and it works now. I also realized the benefits of keeping the data apart from the view. Thank you very much for your help.